# Servidor vinculado no muestra tablas

Tags: sql-server, mysqlconnector

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo Windows 10 Pro de 64BITS y SQL Server 2017, estoy tratando de vincular a SQL Server una servidor MySQL via ODBC he instalado tanto el ODBC de 32 y 64 BITS vinculo el servidor MySQL en ambos casos me dice que la conexion fue exitosa, pero trato de ver las tablas y me da el siguiente error:

> The OLE DB provider "Search.CollatorDSO" for linked server "ServidorVindulado" reported an error. Access denied.
> Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IDBSchemaRowset") from OLE DB provider "Search.CollatorDSO" for linked server "ServidorVindulado". (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Cuanto lanzo una consulta me da igual error:

> An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM myTabla.dbo.Profile" for execution against OLE DB provider "Search.CollatorDSO" for linked server "ServidorVinculado".

Cosa muy rara, con Access si pude realizar la conexion via ODBC a la db MySQL sin problemas, el Office que tengo es tambien de 64BITS.

Alguna idea como puedo solucionar esto?

Saludos

DS

Comment: Si entiendo bien has hecho el servidor vinculado de SQL Server a MySQL, entonces la consulta puedes intentar hacerla usando OPENQUERY, algo así: `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(ServidorVinculado, "SELECT  * FROM ESQUEMA.TABLA")`

Comment: @JosueArriola tal cual tiro la consulta y me devuelve el error que comento: An error occurred while preparing the query "SELECT * FROM myTabla.dbo.Profile" for execution against OLE DB provider "Search.CollatorDSO" for linked server "ServidorVinculado".

Comment: @JosueArriola en Access no tuve problemas para conectar la db MySQL

Comment: El error dice `Access denied`. Revisa los permisos de la cuenta que usas para conectarte.

Comment: @LuisCazares en security>> Be made using this cesurity context tengo el usuario y la contraseña hago la prueba de Test Connection y me dice que es satisfactoria pero lanzo la consulta y da error igual para ver las tablas.

Comment: @LuisCazares en access no tuve necesidad de poner nada tomo el usuario directamente del ODBC

Comment: @LuisCazares
Si era un problema de los permisos de la cuenta, el usuario de acceso era otro.
Gracias Luis.